# Question regarding tug-of-war and tension

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

I am having a hard time understanding these questions regarding tension$-$

1. Is the tension in a rope uniform in a tug of war?
2. If yes, then who wins the game? If no, doesn't that violate Newton's third law?
3. How does the situation change if we play the game in space?

I read several explanations, but all involves setting $m=0$ in string's mass, then $F_1+F_2=0\cdot a=0 \implies F_1=-F_2$. What if we take massive objects (like a block with hooks attached to pull)?

Comment: I always comment that including a human body in the problem never illuminates Newton's Laws.

Answer (score 0):

In a tug of war, each participant adds to the tension in the rope. The maximum tension occurs at the center.  Each team is dependent on friction with the ground and profits from having heavier members. The losing team is moved if they cannot match the tension produced by the other team.  In space, there is no friction, but you might have a tug between two rockets.

Comment: "The losing team is moved if they cannot match the tension produced by the other team." <- I would revise this to say that the losing team is moved if they cannot *push against the ground* as hard as the other team - either by lacking the muscle power, or by failing to achieve the necessary friction against the ground, or (more realistically) some combination of the two.

Comment: @R.W I hear that in space both players move towards each other, why does not one remain stationary while the other comes over?

Comment: @VincentThacker That's not true, as the rope only feels tension from the people behind actually pulling on it - the tension is smallest at the ends of the rope, since there is only one person pulling on it on either side. After the last person, there is zero tension, as the rope just hangs loose since no one's pulling on it. It's the same as if you hang a rope from the ceiling and tie a few weights to it - the top of the rope has to support all the weights, but the bottom of the rope only has to support the bottom weight. Masslessness doesn't change that at all.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Your comment is not very comprehensible to me. (1) This part "*as the rope just hangs loose since no one's pulling on it*" is good, but I am talking about the part of the rope under tension. The slack part isn't exactly of interest here, is it? (2) As for your second part "*if you hang a rope from the ceiling and tie a few weights to it*" this *is* adding mass to the string, which contradicts my condition of masslessness, and consequently, the difference in tension from one point to another will of course be the total weight between the points.

Comment: @VincentThacker A game of tug of war requires participants who have mass. The rope itself may be massless, but the people pulling it aren't. Even if they had no mass, you could still have varying tension by applying force at intervals along the string. My second example is a pretty common pulley problem setup, which usually involves blocks with mass connected by a massless string - the adding point masses doesn't change the fact that the string is massless. At any rate, you could replace the blocks' weight with a massless spring or any other force generator, and it would be the same.